# blog.test not showing welcome page with valet on laravel

Tags: laravel, valet

I am very new to Laravel. 
I have created a local development site blog.test using command `laravel new blog` on MacOS following documentation in Laravel site.

When using command `php artisan serve` in `~/Sites/blog` folder then `blog.test` is showing Laravel welcome page, but when I am using valet for development then `blog.test` is showing `It Works`.

Please help solve this issue. What is the missing step?

I already tried below steps

1. valet reinstallation
2. valet restart
3. valet link

it seems that blog.test is pointing to default `index.html` file of web server instead of `index.php` file in `blog/public` folder of Laravel project.

Do I need to configure the web root directory to `blog/public`
or "valet link" command should take care of this itself?

Comment: Hi Rajesh. Please put more work next time and format your question correctly, fix spelling etc. so it's easier to read by everybody.

Answer (score 0):

"It Works" suggests to me that the Mac's built-in Apache server is handling that request. You just need to disable it in order for Valet to take over.

Run `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` to turn off the built-in Apache server.

You might also have to restart Valet `valet restart` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work.. it is still showing "It Works"

Answer (score 0):

I stopped apache using below command

sudo apachectl stop
and after that I followed below thread

https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/299

It was problem with dnsmasq and dnsmasq.conf file given in thread solved this issue.